# Why does COUNT(*) in my SQL query return several values? How to get one single value for total rows found?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I have a Django class getting some order data from a PostreSQL database. I need to get the number of rows found in a query.

Trying to get the found rows count from the following query with `COUNT(*)`:

When I print the result from the query above, I get a lot of data:

I only want to get a single number, the count of the total rows found and loaded by the select query above. How do I achieve this?

Keep in mind that I'm pretty new to SQL, so I might be missing something obvious to you.

Thanks!

Comment: You have a `group by` clause so you are getting one `count` value for each group. Either fix your SQL to not group, or add the returned counts together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COUNT(expr)` will return a count of the number of non-null values of `expr` in the rows that are retrieved by the `SELECT`.

In your case, you're grouping a bunch togheter and it returns the count for each grouped result row.
You'll probably get the result you're looking for, wrapping it in a subselect.

For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT o.* FROM your_table o ....)
```